# Unity - How to write console

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, console, mouseevent

I add an AR camera my unity project. I use vuforia sdk for AR functions. I want to handle mouse/finger click on screen and get pixel position on screen image. I write below code. To check pixel values, I try to write them on the console. But I don't see anything. AR camera has a .cs file named `DefaultTrackableEventHandler.cs`. I modified it. I run my application an android real device.

**DefaultTrackableEventHandler.cs**

```
if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch (0).phase == TouchPhase.Began) {
        float x = Input.GetTouch(0).position.x;
        float y = Input.GetTouch(0).position.y;
        print("x " + x + " - y " + y);
    }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the `Debug` class to write to the Unity console.

E.g.:

```
if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch (0).phase == TouchPhase.Began) {
    float x = Input.GetTouch(0).position.x;
    float y = Input.GetTouch(0).position.y;
    Debug.Log("x " + x + " - y " + y);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Debug.Log(object)`.
Additional notes:

1. you may use interpolation string to construct a complex message, such as:

```cs
Debug.Log($"a={a}, b={b}, c={Time.deltaTime}");
```

2. `Debug.Log` also prints the current stack trace, so you needn't find a way to print that on your own.